# SSH client connecting to WSL SSH server instead of underlining Windows SSH Server if I use loopback interface IP : 127.0.0.1

Tags: windows, networking, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I am running SSH server on Windows machine and SSH server on WSL Linux distro on the same windows machine. If I do a SSH connection to loopback interface IP : 127.0.0.1, it connects to WSL Linux Distro SSH  server. If I stop SSH server on WSL Linux Distro, then only SSH client connection connecting to SSH server running on windows machine. Is this expected ?

Comment: idk the tech details on this, but it sounds like you're setting up a race condition, then removing one horse from the race. It may end up depending on which service starts first as to which will win.

Comment: Change the port on one of the instances